# How can I determine which client a request originated from?

Tags: meteor

I'm building a control where there is visual feedback as progress is made for the server responding to the input from the client.

The control will be visible on multiple clients at once, and I want the client that made the change on the control to get slightly different feedback to all the others that will see less information about the state changes.

Is there a meteor inbuilt function to uniquely identify each client which I could use for this? If not, how could I go about making a non-repudiated identifier? It would need to identify two different tabs in the same browser as two different clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any easy way to do that built into Meteor, but you can try this depending on your exact use-case.

Here is a technique to track unique client connections per browser window or tab.  Each connectionId below can be thought of as a chat room.  Since the `this.connection.id` property inside a Meteor method is not unique per open window or tab, this will store the connection id along with a timestamp inside a collection.  When the client closes the browser tab or window, you can use the callback inside the server method `this.connection.onClose` to lookup that particular connection by its id along with the timestamp and flag it as closed or offline.

```
Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({

  'client.disconnect': function(connectionId){
    check(connectionId, String);
    let query = {_id: connectionId};
    let options = {$set: {isOnline: false}};
    return Connections.update(query, options);
  },

  'client.connect': function(connectionId){
    check(connectionId, String);
    let lastSessionTime = Number(new Date().getTime());
    let lastSessionId = this.connection.id;
    let offlineQuery = {
      _id: connectionId,
      lastSessionTime: lastSessionTime,
      lastSessionId: lastSessionId
    }
    let offlineOptions = {
      $set: {isOnline: false}
    }

    // When the connection closes, turn this connection offline.
    this.connection.onClose(function(){
      // You could also remove the document.
      Connections.update(offlineQuery, offlineOptions);
    });

    let onlineQuery = {
      _id: connectionId
    }
    let onlineOptions = {
      $set: {
        lastSessionTime: lastSessionTime,
        lastSessionId: lastSessionId,
        isOnline: true}
    }

    var future = new Future();
    Connections.upsert(onlineQuery, onlineOptions, function(err, res){
      if (err){
        future.throw('Connections.online error');
      }else{
        future.return(res);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's a very neat solution, suits just what I need too. Thanks =]